# Retrieve the name of employee who is getting higher salary from each department

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have three different tables like department, employee and salary for SQL Server.

**Its structure**

```
CREATE TABLE department (DeptId INT,DeptName Varchar(100)) 
INSERT INTO department VALUES (1,'Accounts'); 
INSERT INTO department VALUES (2,'Package'); 

CREATE TABLE employee (EmpId INT,DeptId INT,EmpName varchar(20)) 
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (1,1,'Sachin'); 
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (2,1,'Vikas'); 
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (3,2,'Sikha'); 
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (4,2,'Disha'); 

CREATE TABLE salary(EmpId INT,Sal int) 
INSERT INTO salary VALUES (1,400); 
INSERT INTO salary VALUES (2,700); 
INSERT INTO salary VALUES (3,700); 
INSERT INTO salary VALUES (4,900);
```

Result will be:

```
DepName  | EmpName
-----------------
Accounts | Vikas
Package  | Disha
```

Please help me on this, I need a query to find the required result.

> I have tried below query, but not able get EmpName.

```
select DeptName, max(Sal) as Salary from 
(select dep.DeptName, emp.EmpName, sal.Sal from salary as sal
inner join employee emp on emp.EmpId = sal.EmpId 
inner join department dep on dep.DeptId = emp.DeptId) as tbls 
group by DeptName
```

Comment: Can you include your current query and also point out where you are stuck?

Comment: select DeptName, max(Sal) as Salary from 
(select dep.DeptName, emp.EmpName, sal.Sal from salary as sal
inner join employee emp on emp.EmpId = sal.EmpId
inner join department dep on dep.DeptId = emp.DeptId) as tbls
group by DeptName

----not able get EmpName

Comment: I have already mentioned above comment that what I have tried and where stucked as Tim asked.

Comment: You need to [edit] such clarifications into the question, not in a hard to read comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RANK()` to query the salary.

Here is example:

```
select DeptName
      ,EmpName 
from 
(
   select  DeptName
          ,EmpName
          ,rank() over (partition by d.deptid order by sal desc) as ranknum
   from employee as e
   inner join salary as s
   on e.EmpId=s.EmpId
   left join department as d
   on d.DeptId = e.DeptId
) as ranktable
where ranknum = 1
```

Comment: @Rakesh, please, as this solution worked, mark it as valid :-)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `CTE` as well:

```
;WITH maxSalStaff AS (
    SELECT 
        rnk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.DeptId ORDER BY s.Sal DESC),
        d.DeptName, 
        e.EmpName,
        s.Sal
        --ItemID
    FROM department d
    INNER JOIN employee e ON e.DeptId = d.DeptId
    INNER JOIN salary s ON s.EmpId = e.EmpId
)
SELECT * FROM maxSalStaff WHERE rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT T.EmpName, D.DeptName
FROM
(
    SELECT E.EmpId, E.DeptId, E.EmpName, S.Sal, 
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY E.DeptId ORDER BY S.Sal DESC)Rank
    FROM employee E
    INNER JOIN salary s ON E.EmpId = S.EmpId
)T 
INNER JOIN department D ON (T.DeptId = D.DeptId)
WHERE T.Rank=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DENSE_RANK()` in case multiple people can have same salary. Like below

```
WITH cteRowNum AS (
    select 
    e.EmpName,
    d.DeptName,
    sal,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DeptName order by sal desc) as RowNo
    from employee e inner join
    departments d on d.DeptId= e.DeptId inner join
    salary s on e.EmpId= s.EmpId
    )
SELECT EmpName, DeptName, Sal
FROM cteRowNum
WHERE RowNo = 1;
```